# Is there a way in R to specify which column in my data is groups and which is blocks in order to do a Friedman's test? I am comparing results to SPSS

Tags: r

I will give a sample below of how my data is organized but every time I run Friedman's using frieman.test(y =, groups = , blocks= ) it gives me an error that my data is not from an unreplicated complete block design despite the fact that it is.

| score | treatment | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 | 1 |
| 40 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 58 | 2 | 1 |
| 98 | 3 | 1 |
| 89 | 3 | 1 |
| 40 | 3 | 1 |
| 70 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 4 | 1 |
| 28 | 4 | 1 |
| 86 | 5 | 1 |
| 200 | 5 | 1 |
| 40 | 5 | 1 |
| 77 | 1 | 2 |
| 100 | 1 | 2 |
| 90 | 1 | 2 |
| 33 | 2 | 2 |
| 15 | 2 | 2 |
| 25 | 2 | 2 |
| 23 | 3 | 2 |
| 54 | 3 | 2 |
| 67 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 400 | 4 | 2 |
| 16 | 5 | 2 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 |
| 90 | 5 | 2 |

```
library(readr)

sample_data$treatment <- as.factor(sample_data$treatment) #setting treatment as categorical independent variable

sample_data$day <- as.factor(sample_data$day) #setting day as categorical independent variable

summary(sample_data)

friedman3 <- friedman.test(y = sample_data$score, groups = sample_data$treatment, blocks = sample_data$day)

summary(friedman3)
```

the code above gives me the error I described earlier.

However when I convert the csv data to a matrix, Friedman's works but the answer seems wrong as SPSS gives a different result for the degrees of freedom.

```
sample_data$treatment <- as.factor(sample_data$treatment) #converting to categorical independent variable
sample_data$day <- as.factor(sample_data$day)  #converting to categorical independent variable
data = as.matrix(sample_data)
friedman.test(data)
friedman2 <- friedman.test(y = data$score, groups = data$treatment, blocks = data$day)
summary(friedman2)
```

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

I am aware that Friedman's gives me chi-square but I am also wondering how can I get the test statistic instead of the chi-square value.

I am using Rstudio and I am new to R. And I want to know how to specify groups as treatment and day as blocks.

Comment: Are you saying that `SPSS` results are correct?

Comment: In the code, you are converting to `matrix` (`data`) and then extracting with `$` which doesn't work with matrix though

Comment: An issue in the code is converting to `matrix` after changing the 'treatment ' and 'day' to factor.  `matrix` can hold only a single class.  Perhaps you can do `friedman.test(sample_data$score, groups = sample_data$treatment, blocks = sample_data$day)`

Comment: May be you need `sample_data1 <- aggregate(score ~ ., sample_data, FUN = mean);
> friedman.test(sample_data1$score, groups = sample_data1$treatment, blocks = sample_data1$day)#Friedman rank sum test

data:  sample_data1$score, sample_data1$treatment and sample_data1$day
Friedman chi-squared = 1.6, df = 4, p-value = 0.8088`

Comment: Hi @akrun, based on the df it seems as if SPSS is correct because even researching how Friedman's df is calculated, I should get 3 instead of 2 (I am getting 2 in my code). I did not know that it would not work, thanks for letting me know. I also used your suggestion: friedman.test(sample_data$score, groups = sample_data$treatment, blocks = sample_data$day) but it gave me the same error unfortunately. I tried it in both versions of the code (the one converted to matrix and the other that is not converted to matrix)

I am going to try your recent suggestion right now.

Comment: Please see the updated comment above. i.e. summarise the data with `mean` and then apply the `friedman.test`

Comment: Hi, I just used the code you provided, and it gave me the following error: unexpected '>' in " >" . I also tried converting the '>' to '%>%' and also got error and removed the '>' and also gave an error. I tried this in both the code with the matrix and the one without the matrix

Though it is showing a data frame when running your code

Comment: sorry, it is the console symbol.  Just remove the `>` and use only the code

Comment: No worries! now the error I get is "' Error in friedman.test.default(sample_data1$score, groups = sample_data1$treatment,y', 'groups' and 'blocks' must have the same length"

Comment: I don't get any error with the data you posted.  Please use the same code as I showed `sample_data1 <- aggregate(score ~ ., sample_data, FUN = mean); friedman.test(sample_data1$score, groups = sample_data1$treatment, blocks = sample_data1$day)`

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much @akrun!!!! I really appreciate your help! I used the last code you sent me and saw that I had put it incorrectly earlier but now it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could summarise the data by taking the `mean` of the 'score' and then use that summarised data in `friedman.test`

```
sample_data1 <- aggregate(score ~ ., sample_data, FUN = mean)
friedman.test(sample_data1$score, groups = sample_data1$treatment, 
    blocks = sample_data1$day)
```